# val() on checkbox returns an element not the string literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the values of all checked checkboxes. I just want the string literal value.

I try the following:

```
$('input:checked').map(function() { return $(this).val(); })
```

The returned data is:

```
e.fn.init[1]0: "Documents" context: document length: 1 prevObject: e.fn.init[1] __proto__: Object[0]
```

I do not want that. I just want the string "Documents", which is the value of the selected checkbox in my example.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [The doc says](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/): *"Within the function, `this` refers to the global (window) object."*. So you try to get the value of the window object instead of the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `get()` to turn the jQuery object into an array

```
 $('input:checked').map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

See full example below.

```js
var res = $('input:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input checked type="checkbox" id="cbox1" value="first">
<input checked type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="second">
```